# Interpolate out of vector range to split image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vector, interpolation, video-processing

I have an image, and I'm letting the user draw a line on it to pick a region. Now, I would like to take that line (red line in the attached image) and extend it to get to the ends of the frame from both sides (white line in image).
I tried using `interp1` but when I'm trying to get those coordinates on the frame itself, I get NaNs since it's not between the two points that the user picked.

Any suggestions on how to pick those points? Or alternatively, a better way to split the image?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us a [mcve]?

Comment: "extrapolate" is the word

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks, thats the word I was looking for. Got it figured out